# Errors when opening terminal

Tags: node.js, command-line, terminal

When I open terminal I get the following errors. I am working with node.js and Im not sure if this is normal. Any help will be great thanks. I did not instal node with homebrew.

```
-bash: export: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/omarhamouda/npm/bin': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/3.2.9/bin=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/3.2.9/bin:/usr/local/bin': not a valid identifier
```

Contents in my .bash_profile:

```
export $PATH=$PATH:/Users/omarhamouda/npm/bin
export MONGO_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/3.2.9
export PATH=$PATH:$MONGO_PATH/bin 
export $PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Can you give us more details around what you have done/tried so far? Is this after entering a command? Is this after a restart?

Comment: This is when I open terminal. I edited my post to show whats in my .bash_profile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `$PATH=$PATH:...` for your assignments, and those are generating the error messages.

You want to use

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/omarhamouda/npm/bin
export MONGO_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/3.2.9
export PATH=$PATH:$MONGO_PATH/bin 
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

IHTH